# Google API: object oauth2 is not a member of package com.google.api.services

Tags: google-api, playframework-2.0, sbt, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I'm developing a web backend using the Google APIs.
In order to get the email address of a user, you have to send your access token to a Google tokenInfo service, that will return general information (including your email address). In general Google APIs do not return you the mail address of the logged in user.

I'm doing a Scala Play project and I'm using the Java libraries that Google provides. I've found [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java?repo=samples) that shows me how to get information about my access token.

I looked in the .pom file of the sample project where a "google-api-services-oauth2" artifact is included. I also wanted to include this and found the [respective Maven project](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-oauth2).

For the Google APIs there is a general Java API available ("com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.20.0") on which all other libraries including Drive and Calendar API base upon. Since I'm also using the Google calendar API my sbt file looks like this:

```
//add Google Calender API
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 // "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.20.0",
  "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-calendar" % "v3-rev121-1.20.0"//,
  //"com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client-java6" % "1.20.0",
  //"com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-jetty" % "1.20.0"
)

//tokenInfo endpoint to get email address
libraryDependencies += "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-oauth2" % "v2-rev91-1.20.0"
```

However, if I try to create a com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2 object, I get the following error message:

```
object oauth2 is not a member of package com.google.api.services
[error]       com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2
[error]                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I don't quite understand the error since the sample project is doing the exact same. In IntelliJ I also see suggestions of the oauth2 package and I don't know why it does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks correct. I think you just need to run `reload` in your sbt shell to pick up the dependencies in your `build.sbt`. Or just re-start sbt.

Comment: Oh man, you're right... Just for curiosity. Do I always have to restart sbt when I add a new dependency?

Comment: Any time you change the source code of the build (build.sbt) you need to get it re-compiled and run, but instead of restarting just run `reload`.